# Macro in Excel - how do I replace the #Value! with a value in a previous cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of numeric data, however some of the cells contain a #VALUE!. I would like to replace the cells having #VALUE! with the value of the cell in the same column, but previous row. I have attempted the macro code and I obtain a compiler error code 13. Below is the code. I would be grateful for pointers in the right direction.

```
Sub ReplaceErrorValues()
'
' ReplaceErrorValues Macro
' Macro replaces #Value! with the value of the cell in the same column and previous row
'

'Step 1: Declare variables
    Dim priceRange As Range
    Dim priceCell As Range


'Step 2: Define the Target Range
    Set priceRange = Range("D4:D1357")


'Step 3: Start looping through the Days range
    For Each priceCell In priceRange

'Step 4: Do something with every price cell
    If priceCell.Value = #Value! Then
        'Step 5: Create a temporary variable
        Dim previousValue As Double
        priceCell.Select
        priceCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        previousValue = ActiveCell.Value
        priceCell.Select
        ActiveCell.Value = previousValue
     End If

'Step 6: Get the next cell in the Target range
    Next priceCell       


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want to do in your "Step 4"

```
'Step 4: Do something with every price cell
If priceCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrValue) Then
    priceCell.Value = priceCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
End If
```

`CVErr(xlErrValue)` returns a `Variant/Error` value equivalent to what is shown in an Excel cell as `#VALUE!`.

---

If you wanted to check for **any** error type, not just `#VALUE!`, you could use

```
'Step 4: Do something with every price cell
If IsError(priceCell.Value) Then
    priceCell.Value = priceCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
End If
```

`IsError` is a function that tests the value passed to it to see if it is any of the Excel error types (`#VALUE!`, `#N/A`, `#DIV/0!`, `#NAME?`, etc) and returns `True` if it is such a value, or `False` if it isn't.